# Add TimeSpan to DateTime doesn't work

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I want to add new value of time in DateTime

my code in Watch:

```
tsStart {09:00:00}  System.TimeSpan
StartDateTime   {10/17/2014 12:00:00 AM}    System.DateTime
```

c# code for adding TimeSpan into DateTime:

```
StartDateTime.Add(tsStart);
```

value in Watch after added

```
StartDateTime   {10/17/2014 12:00:00 AM}    System.DateTime
```

what I do wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DateTime is immutable type.

```
DateTime newTime = StartDateTime.Add(tsStart);
```

Comment: instead of creating a new DateTime object the code StartDateTime = StartDateTime.Add(tsStart); will resolve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 3):

In comment on JesseJames answer:

```
StartDateTime = StartDateTime.Add(tsStart);
```

The DateTime Add function will return you a new DateTime value consisting out of the DateTime and the Added DateTime Value. However, the DateTime value will not be changed.